# Spring Mongo update by only not null fields of new POJO

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo, mongorepository

**UserModel:**

```
@Document(collection = "USER")
public class UserModel {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<UserModel, String> {

    Optional<UserModel> findByEmail(String email);
    Optional<UserModel> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Saving user document like this:**

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepo;

public someMethod() {
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    //Set all fields....
    userRepo.save(user);
}
```

**Trying to update like this:**

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepo;

public someMethod() {
    UserModel user = new UserModel();
    user.setId("A valid Id got from database by last insert")
    user.setFirstName("New first name");
    // Remaining fields are null now
    userRepo.save(user);
}
```

Here null values will be inserted by MongoRepository.

In there any setup by which I can tell **MongoRepository** to avoid null values while updating?

If we do this by `MongoTemplate updateFirst()` method we have to add `if` conditions for all fields of a POJO. What is the best solution in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data MongoDB - ignore empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457578/spring-data-mongodb-ignore-empty-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch first from the database the user then updates your data and save in the database.

```
UserModel user = userRepo.findById(id); // Fetch from database
user.setFirstName("New first name");    // Update the data
userRepo.save(user);                    // Save in the database
```

Or use custom query to update only selected fields. Here to make it dynamic, create a `Map<String, Object>` from `UserModel` and remove null value.

```
ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> dataMap = oMapper.convertValue(user, Map.class);
map.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
```

And now set the map in `Update` then update in the database.

```
Update update = new Update();
dataMap.forEach(update::set);
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(where("_id").is(id));
mongoTemplate.update(UserModel.class).matching(query).apply(update).first();
```

Comment: This needs an extra query. Our target is to do by one update query along with less code.

Comment: You used Jackson ObjectMapper. right? Well, Making a JSON somehow is a good idea. Let's see is there any other good way to do this.

Comment: @iamcrypticcoder Yes. If your updated nodes are dynamic then this is a good way I think. Or if they are fixed then just add in `Update` is a good way.

Comment: @Eklvya I an opinion regarding this JSON conversion. Basically I had this in my mind. Doesn't it take time in this conversion? Besides Jackson doesn't work good with small payload compared to GSON. I mean the time needed by Jackson.

Comment: @iamcrypticcoder Depends if you use singleton (create a bean one) then it will not take too much time. If you create Map<String, Object> manually then you can avoid this.

Comment: @Eklvyam WIll it work when POJOs are nested. For example, embedded document of the main document. I am trying to find a solution that will work for next objects structure.

Comment: Should work as you are using `Map<String, Object>` but you have to do same think for nested object also

Answer (score 0):

I user an extra class `UserUpdateParam` to collect values,then use Mapstruct to convert `UserUpdateParam` to `UserModel` with annotation `@BeanMapping` to ignore null value. Here is my solution:

#### UserModel:

```java
@Document(collection = "USER")
public class UserModel {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

#### UserUpdateParam:

```java
public class UserUpdateParam {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    
    public UserUpdateParam(){}
}
```

#### UserMapper:

```java
import org.mapstruct.BeanMapping;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    @BeanMapping(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
    void toModel(UserUpdateParam userUpdateParam, @MappingTarget UserModel userModel);
}
```

#### update Code:

```java
class UserDaoImpl {
    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    @Autowited
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void update(UserUpdateParam userUpdateParam) {
        Query query = new org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(userUpdateParam.getId()));
        UserModel userMdoel = mongotemplate.findOne(query, UserModel.class);
        if (userModel == null) {// expr}
        userMapper.toModel(userUpdateParam, userModel);
        mongoTemplate.save(userModel);
    }
}
```