# Spring mongodb: empty list as null (skipped field)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm realizing, `spring-mongodb` is stoeing empty arrays instead of `null` (akka ignore fields).

I mean, currently:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("616441f0216f584747cb5ac7"),
    "identifier" : [
        {
            "use" : "OFFICIAL",
            "system" : "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3",
            "value" : "98860842B",
            "extension" : [ ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, `identifier.extension` is stored as `[]`.

It's correct, since my field contains an empty list. Nevertheless, I'd like to modify this behavior in order to `not store` this field.

Desired:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("616441f0216f584747cb5ac7"),
    "identifier" : [
        {
            "use" : "OFFICIAL",
            "system" : "urn:oid:1.3.6.1.4.1.19126.3",
            "value" : "98860842B"
        },
```

Any ideas?

Comment: hope u initialized `List<String>extension=new ArrayList<>()`. Just do `List<String>extension;`

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: [Same question for empty Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478025/525036) – would probably work too